# LogOn user in Browser

Tags: asp.net, windows-xp, windows-authentication

Hallo.

I need know user name of user which run browser.

If I use

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

or

```
User.Identity.Name
```

it is OK, if I run browser under same account like I'm loged in windows.

But if I run windows as #user1 and browser as #user2, value of this LOGON_USER is empty string.

Is there another way how detect user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is anonymous autentification. There is solution:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/035dcfd0-9a36-4788-b3b6-91dc6a9d9936.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to get your user is:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

This will work as long as the user is authenticated.

Comment: It is empty string too in both cases.

Comment: How are you using the browser as #user2 ?

Comment: In windows, i right-clicked on browser icon, select "Run as..." (maybe another, i have windows localized to other language) and I run it under another user.

Comment: Before, i didn't use windows autentification. Now Yes. Under same user like windows runnings works all ways, under another user works no way.

Comment: I've never run across this situation before. Can you try running the site from FireFox or Chrome? this way you will be prompted for the user's creditials either way.

Comment: In firefox, are empty strings in both cases.

Comment: And in Chrome, there are empty strings too.

Comment: This is very odd indeed. Under the Identity there is a IsAuthenticated flag. Is this set to true? Is there a User#3 that you can test with? Perhaps its an issue with User#2. What about loging into the machine as user#2, instead of just running IE as that user?